# MSTest - Moq setup with a list parameter returns empty list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mstest

I have something like this:

```
WebRequestManagerMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetItemsAsync(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Order>>()))
    .Returns<IEnumerable<Order>>(orders => Task.FromResult<IEnumerabe<Item>>(m_Items.Take(orders.Count())));
```

`m_Items` is a static list I filled in the Class Initialize, and is not empty.

`Orders` is also not empty when I debug the test.

When I call `GetItemsAsync` I get 0 items no matter how many orders there are.

The mock is also static.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a test for your scenario and was able to get it to pass. Take a look at the following

```
[TestClass]
public class MoqSetupWithListParameterTests : MiscUnitTests {
    //m_Items is a static list I filled in the Class Initialize, and is not empty. 
    static IEnumerable<Item> m_Items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Item());
    //The mock is also static. 
    static Mock<IWebRequestManager> WebRequestManagerMock = new Mock<IWebRequestManager>();

    [TestMethod]
    public void Items_Count_Should_Equal_Orders_Count() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = 3;
        //Orders is also not empty when I debug the test.
        var m_Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, expected).Select(i => new Order());
        WebRequestManagerMock
            .Setup(x => x.GetItemsAsync(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Order>>()))
            .Returns<IEnumerable<Order>>(orders => Task.FromResult(m_Items.Take(orders.Count())));

        var sut = WebRequestManagerMock.Object;

        //Act
        //When I call GetItemsAsync I get expected count.
        var actual = sut.GetItemsAsync(m_Orders).Result;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Count());
    }

    public interface IWebRequestManager {
        Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(IEnumerable<Order> enumerable);
    }

    public class Order { }
    public class Item { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason, visual studio doesn't recognize async tests, and I can't run them. Other than that, I moved my mock to the test it self, and it kinda works, only now I have a problem with the  Returns expression - without the list of orders parameter it works, but not with it(the lambda expression)

Comment: @user6251216, edited test so that it is no longer async and still works. note the changes and see it it will recognize the test now. What version of VS are you using and what version of .Net are your targeting

Comment: Originally it was Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4, but I recently upgraded it to 2015 with .NET 4.5. I'm currently having a problem with the `Returns<IEnumerable<Order>>(...)` - it throws a reflection exception regarding the number of parameters, although it does not seem I have a problem with the parenthesis or something. The normal `Returns` works though.

Comment: Return Task for Async tests; do not use void

Comment: @JeroenHeier I had task originally  but poster said that their version was not allowing them to use Task with test

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I'm blind. I didn't notice I'm creating a new instance of my mock in the   TestInitialize method. Thanks for showing me that the problem is in my code and not in moq.